# intercept UITabBar tap

Tags: ios, xcode5, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uitabbar

I need to intercept a UITabBar tap **precisely** so I can conditionally abort moving to the intended ViewController (i.e. conditionally dismiss the tap).

I create my UITabBar in the storyboard. The UITabBar is the root view of my entire app. One of the tabBar items is a profile page (so to speak). If a user does not yet have an account, I want to ignore their clicking on that specific tabBar item. The behavior I seek is that the user will not leave the present ViewController they are in to go to the Tab selected. But instead, I want them to segue to the registration page. Any ideas how I might do this interception?

**UPDATE**

I have managed to add the following method in my AppDelegate. The method is called, but the transition is not intercepted. How do I intercept and abort the transition?

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"Intercept tabBarController in app delegate tap gesture but then do nothing");
}
```

The NSLog line is printed, but transition still occurs.

Comment: what about disable the actual tab-bar item? or you want to redirect the user to the sing-up page in every time when there is no account has been set yet?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are on the right path. [But you should use](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:)

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

If you need more help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go with the [UITabBar delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarDelegate/tabBar:didSelectItem:) of `tabBar:didSelectItem:`

Ex:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
   // Use the item to do further
}
```

Comment: I tried putting the method in the app delegate and then in the present view controller but the method is never called. Are you able to provide a fuller sample?