# UITabbar bottom menu for more option

Tags: ios, swift, menu, uitabbarcontroller

How to achieve the following UI using swift. I tried so many ways.
When I click on More, I need to show three options from the bottom of the current view controller.

Please suggest and provide ideas on how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [intercept UITabBar tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446149/intercept-uitabbar-tap)

Comment: Thank you @Andrew, I tried this delegate method also. But I struggled to show the view on the top of the Tabbar. Could you help with that?. Please.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement delegate methods from UITabBarControllerDelegate:

`func tabBarController(UITabBarController, shouldSelect: UIViewController) -> Bool`

`func tabBarController(UITabBarController, didSelect: UIViewController)`

Then you can just add your view to the tab bar controller's view above the tab bar (with animation if you want to). Or you can add it immediately on load and  toggle visible state.